# Assertion Error, type object 'Student' has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm coding for a class and I get the following assertion error: type object 'Student' has no attribute 'name'

These asserts need to go through:

```
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, "name"), property)
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, "imt_name"), property)
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, "semester"), property)
```

I don't understand why, because I know that the attributes name, imt_name and semester are supposed to be parts of an instance and not attributes of the class.

```
class Student():
    """ ein Student """

    def __init__ (self, name, imt_name, semester):
        self.name = name
        self.imt_name = imt_name
        self.semester = semester

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} in Semester {}".format(self.name, self.imt_name, self.semester)
```

Could the prof have made a mistake? Or is there something that I don't fully understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just answer your question:

> the attributes name, imt_name and semester are supposed to be parts of an instance and not attributes of the class

The `__init__` method have been never called, try:

```
john = Student('john', 'smith', 2)
assert hasattr(john, "name")
assert isinstance(getattr(john, "name"), str)
```

The first assert is checking if instance have an attribute and the seconds one is checking the type of it.

Comment: still get an assertion error, thanks for your contribution

Comment: OH, I see! So the assert is probably generalized and switches up.. makes sense to me & works fine with str :)

Comment: after you've checked that attribute exists -- no need to use `getattr`, just use dot operator

Comment: @ranifisch is your name john? ;)

Comment: I used your instance's example, but you copy *right* the answer from me. can be easly seen from your edit history..

Comment: @ranifisch yes, indeed, I used part of your answer to improve full answer.

Comment: @jasiuuu part of my answer which is the answer, as i said, funny and disrespecting imo

Comment: @ranifisch I respect your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if instance of a given class a given attribute using the [`hasattr`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/hasattr) function:

```
    john = Student("A", "b", "c")
    assert hasattr(john, "name")
```

Comment: Your assert works, but the assert assert isinstance(getattr(john, "name"), property) still doesn't go through.

Comment: That's because getattr returns the value of the attribute specified. in my case,
getattr(john, "name") returns "A"